# How to use ParseLiveQuery with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing

I have tried searching for working examples of how to get ParseLiveQuery to work without any success.

I have successfully set up the liveQueries on my server however I am unable to subscribe and therefore handle events.

The github guide states you can simply subscribe by `query.subscribe()` however this doesn't appear, the only option I have available is `query._PF_objc_subscribe()` which doesn't seem to work.

When using this to try and handle events I get errors such as:

*No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.14.2)
__nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 16 Connection has no connected handler*

Has anyone managed to get ParseLiveQuery working and can share the correct and current code to use?

Comment: Has anyone managed to get LiveQuery working? I have tried all the example codes in the guides but still nothing works. If I use query._PF_objc_subscribe() I can see from the server logs that the client connects as it displays 'Create new client' however I am unable to receive updates. None of the code examples provided match what is accepted within Xcode. Alternatively, is there any other method using Parse server to allow real time messaging?

Comment: Did you make any headway? I'm also having this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am still trying to find how to use live query but not having any luck.